# How to perform navigation in Windows Store App using Blank App Template

Tags: javascript, navigation, windows-store-apps

I'm making a game using JavaScript, currently I'm using `window.location = "somepage.html"` to perform navigation but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it. As I said in the title I've choosed Blank App Template so I do not have any `navigator.js` or something like.

Can you guys tell me the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can use window.location to perform navigation, I'm sure you've already noticed a few of the downsides:

- The transition between pages goes through a black screen, which is an artifact of how the underlying HTML rendering engine works.
- You lose your script context between pages, e.g. you don't have any shared variables or namespaces, unless you use HTML5 session storage (or WinRT app data).
- It's hard to wire up back buttons, e.g. you have to make sure each destination page knows what page navigated to it, and then maintain a back stack in session storage.

It's for these reasons that WinJS + navigator.js created a way to do "pages" via DOM replacement, which is the same strategy used by "single page web apps." That is, you have a div in default.html within which you load an unload DOM fragments to give the appearance of page navigation, while you don't actually ever leave the original script context of default.html. As a result, all of your in-memory variables persist across all page navigations.

The mechanics work like this: [WinJS.Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229778.aspx) provides an API to manage navigation and a backstack. By itself, however, all it really does is manage a backstack array and fire navigation-related events. To do the DOM replacement, something has to be listening to those events.

Those listeners are what navigator.js implements, so that's a piece of code that you can pull into any project for this purpose. Navigator.js also implements a custom control called the PageControlNavigator (usually Application.PageControlNavigator) is what implements the listeners.

That leave the mechanics of how you define your "pages." This is what the [WinJS.UI.Pages API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770584.aspx) is for, and navigator.js assumes that you've defined your pages in this way. (Technically speaking, you can define your own page mechanisms for this, perhaps using the low-level [WinJS.UI.Fragments API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229781.aspx) or even implementing your own from scratch. But WinJS.UI.Pages came about because everyone who approached this problem basically came up with the same solution, so the WinJS team provided one implementation that everyone can use.)

Put together then:

- You define each page as an instance of WinJS.UI.Pages.PageControl, where each page is identified by its HTML file (which can load its own JS and CSS files). The JS file contains implementations of a page's methods like ready, in which you can do initialization work. You can then build out any other object structure you want.
- In default.html, define a single div for the "host container" for the page rendering. This is an instance of the PageControlNavigator class that's defined in navigator.js. In its data-win-options you specify "{home: }" for the initial page that's loaded.
- Whenever you want to switch to another page, call WinJS.Navigation.navigate with the identifier for the target page (namely the path to its .html file). In response, it will fire some navigating events.
- In response, the PageControlNavigator's handlers for those events will load the target page's HTML into the DOM, within its div in default.html. It will then unload the previous page's DOM. When all of this gets rendered, you see a page transition--and a smooth one because we can animate the content in and out rather than go through a black screen.
- In this process, the previous page control's unload method is called, and the init/load/processed/ready methods of the new page control are called.

It's not too hard to convert a blank app template into a nav template project--move your default.html/.css/.js content into a page control structure, add navigator.js to default.html (and your project), and put a PageControlNavigator into default.html. I suggest that you create a project from the nav app template for reference. Given the explanation above, you should be able to understand the structure.

For more details, refer to Chapter 3 of my free ebook, *[Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2)*, where I talk about app anatomy and page navigation with plenty of code examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I ended up using a Nav App template as reference as you said. I modified the css for some pages to give the illusion of multipage navigation.
Also thanks for the book!